# Difference between Stanford CoreNLP and Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

What is the difference between using CoreNLP (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html) and the standalone distribution Stanford NER (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html) for doing Named Entity Recognition? I noticed that the standalone distribution comes with a GUI, but are there any other differences in terms of supported functionality?

I'm trying to decide which one to use for a commercial purpose. I'm working on English models only.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in terms of what algorithm is run.  I would suggest the full version since you can use the pipeline code.  But both versions use the exact same code for the actual NER part.